# error: no match for 'operator!='

Tags: c++, vector

```
void Verylong::normal()
{
    for (auto i = lnum.begin(); i != lnum.back(); ++i)
    {   
        if (abs(*i) >= base){
            if (*i > 0)
            {
                if (i == lnum.back() - 1)
                    lnum.push_back(*i / base);
                else    
                    *(i+1) += *i / base;  

                *i %= base; 
            }
            else{
                if (i == lnum.back() - 1)
                    lnum.push_back(*i / base);
                else    
                    *(i+1) += *i / base;

                *i = base + (*i % base);   //  т.к  *i всегда отриц. а base всегда полож., эквивалентно *i = base - |i % base| 
            }
        }
    }

    if (lnum[lnum.size() - 1] < 0){
        lnum[lnum.size() - 1] *= -1;
        _sign = false;
    }
    else 
        _sign = true;
}
```

выдает ошибку на строке for (auto i = lnum.begin(); i != lnum.back(); ++i)
в чем проблема?

Comment: lnum это vector<int>

Answer (score 1):

```
for (auto i = lnum.begin(); i != lnum.back(); ++i)
```

`i` имеет тип `std::vector<int>::iterator`, тогда как `lnum.back()` возвращает объект типа `int`. Не существует оператора `!=`, который может сравнить `int` и `std::vector<int>::iterator`, о чём Вас компилятор и уведомляет.

Когда Вы работаете с итераторами, тогда нужно использовать пару `begin()/end()(cbegin()/cend())`

Когда Вы работаете со значениями, тогда можно использовать пару `front()/back()`

Но нужно понимать,что они существуют для разных целей и не могут быть совмещены друг с другом напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем там `lnumb.back()` я не совсем понял. Кроме того этот вызов на пустом контейнере приводит к неопределенному поведению. Больше ничего не могу сказать.

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = lnumb.begin(); it != lnumb.end(); ++it) {
    /* std::cout << *it; ... */
}
```

Comment: да, всем спасибо, перепутал back() и end()